# How to block all UI actions

Tags: android

I currently have a profile page that lets users change their picture in Android.

When loading the new image, I want to disable all input actions (clicks/swipes) in the activity and display a semi-transparent film over it with a loading progress bar.

[image]

Unfortunately, my current implementation does not work as intended - actions are still getting passed to the under layers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context="com.example.www.android_image_cropper_v2.ProfileActivity"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choose_button"
            android:text="Choose picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            android:text="Remove picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/blocking_film"
        android:visibility="gone"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#33000000">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the code for the activity

```
package com.example.www.android_image_cropper_v2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public Button       CHOOSE_BUTTON;
    public Button       REMOVE_BUTTON;
    public LinearLayout BLOCKING_FILM;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        CHOOSE_BUTTON = (Button)       findViewById(R.id.choose_button);
        REMOVE_BUTTON = (Button)       findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
        BLOCKING_FILM = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blocking_film);

        CHOOSE_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(choose_listener);
        REMOVE_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(remove_listener);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener choose_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            BLOCKING_FILM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    public View.OnClickListener remove_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // pass
        }
    };
}
```

## How do I make it so that `Blocking Film` traps all UI actions? (ALL, not just CLICK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:clickable="true"` in the `blocking_film`.

Comment: What about preventing other actions (Swipe/etc)

Comment: Sorry, I was replying before your edit. I'm on my mobile right now so can't post anything much longer. Maybe try to set some motion event listener.